# Convert SQL which includes multiple CASE WHEN and PARTITION BY statements into DAX

Tags: sql, dax

I'm new to DAX and am struggling to convert the following SQL:

```
CASE WHEN 
    (MAX
        (CASE WHEN SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE = -1 THEN (30990101) ELSE SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE END) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY APPOINTMENT_ID) = 30990101)
  THEN -1 ELSE (MAX(SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY APPOINTMENT_ID)) END SKEY_APPOINTMENT_END_DATE
```

For a bit of context here is an example of the data I'm working with:

[image: Table 1]

If an appointment ID has -1 as an end date, the goal is to return that, otherwise return the most recent end date. A -1 end date means that post has not ended or has not be given a future end date. The 30990101 is used because a value in the SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE will not exceed this. There will always be multiple records for each Appointment ID with different dates, and won't always include a -1.

The end result should look like this:

[image: Table 2]

I've tried the following DAX:

```
SWITCH( TRUE()
        ,SWITCH(TRUE()
            ,CALCULATE(MAX('Appointment History'[SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE] = -1, (30990101))
                ,ALLEXCEPT('Appointment History', 'Appointment History'[Appointment ID]))) = 30990101, -1
        ,CALCULATE(MAX('Appointment History'[SKEY_ACTUAL_END_DATE]),
            ALLEXCEPT('Appointment History', 'Appointment History'[Appointment ID]))
        )
```

This doesn't work because of the second SWITCH, I think. I'm not sure if you can have nested SWITCH statements in DAX? I'm struggling to get my head around it to be honest. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DAX, but... is `SWICH` mis-spelled?  You have both `SWITCH` and `SWICH`

Comment: Good spot. It is misspelled which I will edit now. With the correct spelling though, my DAX statement returns #ERROR.

Comment: This does not look like a good task for DAX; I'd recommend to do this either at the source (data warehouse), or in PowerQuery. DAX is a  language for interactive queries, not for data transformation.

Comment: I had considered applying the logic at source if this failed. Perhaps that would be best then. Thanks for the advice.